# when I click in CommandButton doesnt go to another page

Tags: java, jsf, commandbutton

Im trying to go to another JSF page and add an object to an ArrayList, with the button below, the scope of the managed bean is in Session, but when i click the button doesnt go to the other page.

I edited the entire code to show only the important parts, so the Button is in a Form, and the @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped anotations of the managed bean are in place.

XHTML

```
<p:commandButton value="Ingresar" action="#{cliente.formularioGo()}"/>
```

Ciente JSF Managed Beans

```
public String formularioGo() {

    entidades.Cliente cliente = new entidades.Cliente(celular, nombre, direccion);       

    listaCliente.add(cliente);//here I store objects in an ArrayList

    return "fomularioVenta";// This should take me to other JSF page called "formularioVenta"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, your button should be in a form;

```
<p:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Ingresar" action="#{cliente.formularioGo()}"/>
</p:form>
```

and your class should have annotations like;

```
@ManagedBean(name="cliente")
@SessionScoped
```

Comment: I have those,sorry. I just chooped the code to show the relevant lines